# Replace a pattern in a file with a long string

Tags: shell, sed, awk, posix, replace

I'm writing a little shell script to generate a directory listing. To make the output easily customizable, the script just builds a HTML-table and than should replace a specific token in a template file with that table and write it to `stdout`.

**Example:**
Template file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head><title>Directory Listing</title></head>
    <body>
        {{LISTING}}
    </body>
</html>
```

`{{LISTING}}` should be replaced with the listing (which is stored in a shell variable).

The problem here is, that a simple `sed 's/{{LISTING}}/$listing/'` would be limited to the maximum argument length which doesn't work with long listings.

How can I replace a pattern in a file with a long string using POSIX utilities?

EDIT:
To add more clarification: My current solution is like that:

```
awk '{ gsub(A, B); print; }' A="{{LISTING}}" B="$listing" < $template
```

`$listing` gets expanded as awk is invoked, but this can exceed argument length limits, since `$listing` can be really long. For example, when generating a listing of `/usr/lib`, I get an error:

```
/bin/awk: Argument list too long
```

I'm thinking whether there is a solution to replace a pattern in a textfile with `stdin`.

Comment: @wlhim is there any issue with using awk and bash ?

Comment: I don't have a problem with them, I just couldn't come up with a solution without specifying the replacement text (which is in $listing) as an argument, since $listing can be too long and I get an error: "/bin/awk: Argument list too long".

Comment: I have updated the ans, please once check and let me know..

Comment: bash: /bin/sed: Argument list too long

Comment: once check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289551/argument-list-too-long-error-for-rm-cp-mv-commands

Answer (score 1):

If there are 3 files:

- old: the original data
- replace: the large batch of text you want to insert
- newfile: where the replacements will be saved

You should be able to do the following with a standard shell

```
#!/bin/sh
for line in `cat old`; do
  if [ $line == "text to match" ]; then
    cat replace >> newfile
  else
    echo $line >> newfile
  fi
done
```

Comment: There are two caveats with `for in` and `while read`: 1. Trailing characters included in IFS are stripped (for example trailing spaces) 2. The token has to be on its own line (not in the middle of text; this is only a minor issue for me)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `xargs` since it knows about argument size limits:

```
cp "$template_file" "$output_file" || exit 1
echo "$listing" \
| xargs -I arg sed -i 's/{{LISTING}}/arg {{LISTING}}/' "$output_file" \
| sed -i 's/ {{LISTING}}//' "$output_file"
```

The caveat here is that `xargs` strips trailing new lines in file names.

Comment: The template file should be specified with a command line option: `dir-listing.sh -t TEMPLATE`

Comment: @wlhlm Edited answer. See if this helps.